# What is difference between checkpoint_timeout and checkpoint_completion_target in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, database-internals, checkpoint

I am MSSQL guy and I find it a bit difficult to understand the main purpose of checkpoint_completion_target. I cannot find a comprehensive resource that would explain more clearly the difference between checkpoint_timeout and checkpoint_completion_target parameters in PostgreSQL.

Comment: https://www.depesz.com/2010/11/03/checkpoint_completion_target/  or https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/basics-of-tuning-checkpoints/

Answer (score 3):

`checkpoint_timeout` specifies the interval at which checkpoints happen, unless they are triggered by the `CHECKPOINT` statement or the amount of WAL written (`max_wal_size`).

`checkpoint_completion_target` configures how slow the checkpoint is written. A value of 0.8 would make PostgreSQL write checkpoints slow enough that the current checkpoint is done when 80% of the estimated time to the start of the next checkpoint has passed. Spreading checkpoints as much as possible is a good idea to avoid I/O spikes.